Issues Installing Chrome Extensions in Dockerized Chromium
I'm trying to install Chrome extensions in a Dockerized Chromium setup, but I'm running into several issues. I have already extracted the .crx files into their respective folders and placed them in the /home/main/chromium/config1/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/ directory. Each folder is named according to the extension's ID and contains the necessary files, including manifest.json.
Directory Structure: I have the following structure for my extensions:
/home/main/chromium/config1/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/
    ├── caacbgbklghmpodbdafajbgdnegacfmo/  (Gradient Sentry Node)
    │    └── 1.0.9_0/   
    │         ├── manifest.json
    │         └── (other necessary files)
    └── fpdkjdnhkakefebpekbdhillbhonfjjp/  (DAWN Validator)
         └── 1.0.6_0/
              ├── manifest.json
              └── (other necessary files)

Chromium seems to remove files automatically(It is not clear under what circumstances, perhaps after restarting docker). When I extract the .crx file to /home/main/chromium/config1/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/\<ID_OF_EXTENSION\> Chromium does not detect it in the Extensions tab.
This is my code:
#!/bin/bash

show() {
  echo "$1"
}

showw() {
  echo -e "\033[33m$1\033[0m"
}

# Asking for connection method: localhost or external IP
read -p "Do you want to run the browsers on localhost? (y/n): " LOCALHOST_CHOICE

if [ "$LOCALHOST_CHOICE" == "y" ] || [ "$LOCALHOST_CHOICE" == "Y" ]; then
  IP="localhost"
else
  IP=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)
  if [ -z "$IP" ]; then
    show "Could not obtain external IP address."
    exit 1
  fi
fi

# Asking for username
read -p "Enter username: " USERNAME

# Asking for password, input will be hidden
read -s -p "Enter password: " PASSWORD
echo  # New line for better display
read -s -p "Confirm password: " PASSWORD_CONFIRM
echo  # New line

# Checking if passwords match
if [ "$PASSWORD" != "$PASSWORD_CONFIRM" ]; then
  show "Passwords do not match. Please restart the script and enter the passwords correctly."
  exit 1
fi

# Asking for the number of browsers
read -p "Enter the number of browsers to launch: " BROWSER_COUNT

CREDENTIALS_FILE="$HOME/vps-browser-credentials.json"
cat <<EOL > "$CREDENTIALS_FILE"
{
  "username": "$USERNAME",
  "password": "$PASSWORD"
}
EOL

# Downloading the latest Docker image for Chromium
show "Downloading the latest Docker image for Chromium..."
if ! docker pull lscr.io/linuxserver/chromium:latest; then
  show "Failed to download the Docker image for Chromium."
  exit 1
else
  show "Docker image for Chromium successfully downloaded."
fi

# Launching the specified number of browsers
for i in $(seq 1 "$BROWSER_COUNT"); do
  CONTAINER_NAME="browser$i"
  PORT=$((10000 + i - 1))  # Each container uses a unique port
  CONFIG_DIR="$HOME/chromium/config$i"  # Unique directory for each container

  # Creating config directory if it does not exist
  mkdir -p "$CONFIG_DIR"

  if [ "$(docker ps -q -f name=$CONTAINER_NAME)" ]; then
    show "Container $CONTAINER_NAME is already running."
  else
    show "Starting container $CONTAINER_NAME with Chromium..."

    # Running the container
    docker run -d --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" \
      --privileged \
      -e TITLE=CustomBrowser \
      -e DISPLAY=:1 \
      -e PUID=1000 \
      -e PGID=1000 \
      -e CUSTOM_USER="$USERNAME" \
      -e PASSWORD="$PASSWORD" \
      -e LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 \
      -e USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36" \
      -v "$CONFIG_DIR:/config" \
      -p "$PORT:3000" \
      --shm-size="2gb" \
      --restart unless-stopped \
      lscr.io/linuxserver/chromium:latest

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      show "Container $CONTAINER_NAME started successfully."
    else
      show "Failed to start container $CONTAINER_NAME."
      exit 1
    fi
  fi

  showw "Open this address http://$IP:$PORT/ to access browser $CONTAINER_NAME externally."
done

showw "Enter this username: $USERNAME in the browser."
showw "Enter this password in the browser."

# Function for installing local extensions
install_local_extension() {
  local EXTENSION_ID=$1
  local VERSION_FOLDER=$2
  local CONTAINER_NAME=$3

  # Path to the local extensions directory
  LOCAL_EXTENSION_DIR="$HOME/chromium/extensions/$EXTENSION_ID/$VERSION_FOLDER/"
  # Path to the directory where extensions need to be copied in the container
  CONTAINER_EXTENSION_DIR="/config/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/$EXTENSION_ID"

  # Creating directory in the container
  docker exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" mkdir -p "$CONTAINER_EXTENSION_DIR"

  # Copying all files from version to container directory
  if docker cp "$LOCAL_EXTENSION_DIR." "$CONTAINER_NAME:$CONTAINER_EXTENSION_DIR/"; then
    show "Successfully installed extension $EXTENSION_ID in container $CONTAINER_NAME."
  else
    show "Error installing extension $EXTENSION_ID in container $CONTAINER_NAME."
  fi
}

# Prompt for installing local extensions
while true; do
  read -p "Do you want to install local extensions? (y/n): " INSTALL_LOCAL_EXTENSIONS
  if [[ "$INSTALL_LOCAL_EXTENSIONS" == "y" || "$INSTALL_LOCAL_EXTENSIONS" == "Y" ]]; then
    read -p "Enter extension ID (e.g., fpdkjdnhkakefebpekbdhillbhonfjjp): " EXTENSION_ID
    read -p "Enter version folder (e.g., 1.0.9_0): " VERSION_FOLDER
    read -p "Enter container name (e.g., browser1): " CONTAINER_NAME
    install_local_extension "$EXTENSION_ID" "$VERSION_FOLDER" "$CONTAINER_NAME"
    
    read -p "Do you want to install another? (y/n): " MORE_EXTENSIONS
    if [[ "$MORE_EXTENSIONS" != "y" && "$MORE_EXTENSIONS" != "Y" ]]; then
      break
    fi
  else
    break
  fi
done


I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag. Also see correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization - your all-upper-case variable names may be clobbering some environment variables (I see at least 1 that's used by some shells).
